# Can HTML5 meter value accept setAttribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How should I go about pushing the value of a variable to an input value with Javascript? I know is possible to set other element attributes with setAttribute but I can't get anything to set in the "value".

Here's the current javascript function:

```
function testfunc(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("meter")[0].setAttribute("value", "2000");   
}​
```

And the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>untitled</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <button onclick="testfunc()">Find my elevations</button>  
    <meter value="900" min="0" max="5280" id="high">500/5280</meter>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

​

What i'd like to do is replace the current set value of 900 with the testfunc() value of 2000. The 2000 is completely arbitrary as it will be a dynamically generated number in the live app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML 5: 4.10.17 The meter element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-meter-element.html#dom-meter-value) suggests that you can just do

```
document.getElementById("high").value = /* float value between min and max */
```

The relevant portions of that spec are

> The following inequalities must hold, as applicable:
>
> - minimum ≤ value ≤ maximum
> - minimum ≤ low ≤ maximum (if low is specified)
> - minimum ≤ high ≤ maximum (if high is specified)
> - minimum ≤ optimum ≤ maximum (if optimum is specified)
> - low ≤ high (if both low and high are specified)
>
> ...
>
> The `value` IDL attribute, on getting, must return the actual value. On setting, the given value must be converted to the best representation of the number as a floating point number and then the `value` content attribute must be set to that string.

Comment: From reading the spec, it sounds like it may expect you to set both the value property, as well as the value content attribute.

Comment: So it would look something like this??

function testfunc(){
document.getElementById("high").value = setAttribute("value", "2000");}

Comment: @CNCPTS, no, `document.getElementById("high").value = 20000;` should work just fine.

Comment: I figured that out after a few tests, ended up passing it a variable. Like so document.getElementById('altim').value = theAltitude; Thanks for the help.